# Integrating React Native View above Custom Native Camera in Android - Display Issue

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

• Created a custom camera using a native module.
• Now I have called this custom camera in my react native component
• Once I call this, the camera opens and the corresponding layout (XML file) also opens above the camera.
• I want to display react native's view above the custom native camera screen instead of the Android's XML layout.

I have used callback but it didn't work
I want to display the layout for the custom Android native module using react native inside the View component.

Comment: Do you want an overlay above the camera screen ?
Which cameral module are you using ?

Comment: Am using CameraX module of Android in React native

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :
https://medium.com/@sisongqolosi/vision-camera-react-native-326b9dfb3188

Solution 2 :
https://www.fullstacklabs.co/blog/react-native-camera

Solution 3 :
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/281

Solution 4 :
Make sure your overlay component's z-index is greater than your custom camera view's. It might be necessary to experiment with these parameters in order to get the desired effect of overlaying.